# Mysql - Triggers de valores derivados

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Pesquisei e não achei em lugar algum.

Estou iniciando nos estudos em Banco de dados e preciso da seguinte ajuda:
Uma tabela **Turma** possui a seguinte estrutura:

Id_turma(auto incrementável)
Max_alunos(numero máximo de alunos)
**soma_alunos**(coluna derivada do tanto de alunos que estuda no estabelicmento)

Essa tabela é ligada em uma relação com **Estuda_em**, outra tabela que também é lingada com a tabela **Estudante**, fazendo assim uma ligação Many-To-Many. A tabela **Estuda_em** possui apenas foreign keys,Id_aluno e Id_turma.

A minha intenção é, toda vez que eu inserir no **Estuda_em** a Id_aluno e  Id_turma, ter o valor soma_alunos somado por 1 garantindo que ele seja menor ou igual max_aluno

Resumindo: Toda vez que eu inserir uma tupla na tabela **Estuda_em** somar +1 no atributo derivado **soma_aluno**.

Segue um exemplo do código que não certo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER adcionaaluno AFTER INSERT ON Estuda_em

FOR EACH ROW begin

UPDATE turma.soma_alunos =  soma_alunos + 1

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Pedro.

Sua resposta está perto, mas ainda falta alguns detalhes. A trigger realmente é  `AFTER INSERT` e na tabela `Estuda_em` no entanto seu código precisa de mais duas coisas:

1. Localizar o item exato a ser modificado na tabela `turma`
2. Corrigir o `UPDATE` para usar a tag `SET`

O seguinte código - que expandi do seu - consegue isso:

```
CREATE TRIGGER adcionaaluno AFTER INSERT ON Estuda_em

FOR EACH ROW begin

UPDATE turma SET turma.soma_alunos =  soma_alunos + 1 WHERE turma.Id_turma = NEW.ID_turma;

END
```